# ostringstream problem with int in c++

Tags: c++, xcode, string, macos

I would expect the following code to output `hello5`. Instead, it only outputs `hello`.
It seems to be a problem with trying to output an int to the `ostringstream`.
When I output the same directly to `cout` I receive the expected input. Using XCode 3.2 on Snow Leopard.

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
 int myint = 5;
 string mystr = "hello";
 string finalstr;
 ostringstream oss;

 oss << mystr << myint;
 finalstr = oss.str();

 cout << finalstr;


 return 0;
}
```

**EDIT: See the answer I posted below. This seems to be created by a problem in the Active Configuration 'Debug' in XCode 3.2 on Snow Leopard**

Comment: I get `hello5` using both Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 and Intel C++ Compiler 11.1.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416096/c-debug-builds-broke-in-snow-leopard-x-code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603300/xcode-3-2-1-and-c-string-fails

Comment: This is the correct solution. It says to switch the compiler from GCC 4.2 to GCC 4.0 (in Project Settings, DEBUG configuration). Program runs correctly after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the Active Configuration in XCode from 'Debug' to 'Release' works as a workaround.

Comment: I can only concur...when testing within an Xcode c++ std++ 10.6 template with DEBUG the int is not outputted. 10.5 with DEBUG does work ok. I suggest you file a bug report. http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: It definitely has something to do with the `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1` option. When given to my previous command line test it now showed the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is correct, it writes hello5 on my Windows 7 machine. Maybe the problem is rather that you don't write a std::endl or something which might confuse your OS.

Comment: Your problem seems to be related to your compiler or your shell. Try attaching a debugger and see what happens behind the scenes.

Comment: Can you test with debug enabled? ie `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1` like on a unix box? Curious if is's a Mac only problem

Answer (score 2):

Yep, tested on this end (windows XP Pro) and it works swimmingly

Comment: Can you test with debug enabled? ie `-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG=1` like on a unix box? Curious if is's a Mac only problem

Comment: I ran it through a debugger and didn't see anything unusual...sorry

Comment: I can imagine MS have their own implementation of the stream classes. Mac relies on the GLIB sources. Wonder if it's isolated to the Mac...

Answer (score 1):

I just tested and it worked just fine on my Mac with Xcode 3.2.1 and Snow Leopard. It not that your prompt is shadowing the output? Try add an `endl` to the cout line?

**-- Edit --**

## My test suite

- `c++ test.cpp` -- works fine
- `c++ -D_GLICXX_DEBUG=1 test.cpp` -- fail
- `c++ -arch i386 -D_GLICXX_DEBUG=1 test.cpp` -- works fine

What can we say about this? In short, Debug version of 64 bit stdc++ seem to be broken.

Comment: nope! tried and no cigar, but get this: if I flip the output (int first, string second), then NOTHING shows up. ( oss << myint << mystr;) in fact, anything after outputting an int doesn't show up.

Comment: How do you compile it? I did a plain `c++ text.cpp`